# Create Bootstrap dropdown menu with and without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently working through this Bootstrap 3 tutorial at TutorialRepublic: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-dropdowns.php

On that page there are among others two ways to create a dropdown menu:

1. using data attributes
2. using JavaScript

**Markup for way 1:**

```
<div class="bs-example">
   <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Markup for way 2:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
});  
</script>
<div class="bs-example">
   <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the tutorial says:

> The data-toggle="dropdown" is still required for the dropdown's trigger element regardless of whether you call the dropdown via JavaScript or data-api.

**So my question is:** What is the point in using way 2 if one still needs to specify the data attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First : you can add the toggle attributes programmatically.

Second, by using jQuery you can control when you want your dropdown instantiated in order to interact with it. For instance to listen for events coming fro the drowdown as shown in your link.

If you just need pur HTML with all default behaviour of dropdown, go for 1, if you need something else, you'll see that you'll need often to add some javascript and control the object's life yourself.